# Regex to detect and replace an <a> tag?

Tags: php, html, regex, hyperlink, preg-match

If I were to use `preg_replace`, what would be the corresponding regex in order to determine whether or not a string contains one or more `<a>` tags, and then add `rel="nofollow"` to it?

So it would take this:

```
Hi! What's up? <a href="http://test.com">Click here</a> to check out
<a href="http://apple.com">my</a> website. This is <b>also</b> a test.
```

And turn it into this:

```
Hi! What's up? <a href="http://test.com" rel="nofollow">Click here</a>
to check out <a href="http://apple.com" rel="nofollow">my</a> website. This is
<b>also</b> a test.
```

Comment: Regex isn't the best option. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: just match the contents of the `<a>` tag and modify it.

```
$new_text = preg_replace('#<a\b((?![^>]*rel="nofollow")[^>]+)>#', '<a \1 rel="nofollow">', $your_starting_text);
```

The purpose of the negative lookahead (`(?![^>]*rel="nofollow")`) is to avoid double-adding the `rel` attribute.  It says, don't match this `<a>` tag if it has `rel="nofollow"` already. *Edited to fix double-adding glitch.*

Demo:

```
$your_starting_text = 'Hi! What\'s up? <a href="http://test.com" rel="nofollow">Click here</a>
    to check out <a href="http://apple.com" rel="nofollow">my</a> website. This is
    <b>also</b> a test.';
$new_text = preg_replace('#<a\b((?![^>]*rel="nofollow")[^>]+)>#', '<a \1 rel="nofollow">', $your_starting_text);
echo htmlentities($new_text);
```

This outputs:

```
Hi! What's up? <a href="http://test.com" rel="nofollow">Click here</a> to check out <a href="http://apple.com" rel="nofollow">my</a> website. This is <b>also</b> a test.
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `DOM` is a better approach over using regular expression here.

```
$html = <<<DATA
Hi! What's up? <a href="http://test.com">Click here</a> to check out
<a href="http://apple.com">my</a> website. This is <b>also</b> a test.
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$links = $xpath->query('//a');

foreach($links as $link) { 
   $link->setAttribute('rel', 'nofollow');
}

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output

```
Hi! What's up? <a href="http://test.com" rel="nofollow">Click here</a> 
to check out <a href="http://apple.com" rel="nofollow">my</a> website. This is 
<b>also</b> a test.
```

Comment: How could I store the edited HTML in a variable? So then I could input it into my database.

Comment: `$data = $dom->saveHTML();`